# Google My Maps - data layer as JSON

Tags: json, google-maps

Is there any way that I can access a data layer from Google My Maps as JSON? Basically I want the same data that you get by selecting "Open data table" plus, of course, the coordinates.

Comment: I really don't understand why the negative vote! I searched through the documentation and I couldn't find anything. I doubt that I'm the only one trying to integrate a Google service into another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used togeojson. And here's the code.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");
var tj = require('togeojson');
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

var requestOptions = {
        headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'}
        , followRedirect: true
        , followAllRedirects: true
};


function retrieveTrack(track, trackUrl) {
    console.log("Retrieving track " + track + " from " + trackUrl);
    request(trackUrl, requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("Response:" + response.statusCode);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            fs.writeFile(track + ".kml", body, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("Track retrieved: " + track);
            });
            convertTrack(track);
        }
    });
}

function convertTrack(track) {
    fs.readFile(getKmlPath(track), function (error, data) {
        var json = tj.kml(jsdom(data));
        fs.writeFile(track + ".json", JSON.stringify(json, null, "\t"), function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("Track converted: " + track);
        }); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like [MyMaps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) only supports exporting data as KML. I have a [tool](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5b.html) that will import KML and export it as JSON (not GeoJSON), you should be able to code something to do that translation.

I did that with [this MyMap](https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zNPjLbo835mE.k3TvWfqGG-AU), created [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/blitz-gmap-editor_test5b_BalboaParkJson.html)

There are also a couple of tools (found from a quick search):

- [toGeoJSON](http://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/)
- [ogr2ogr : Converting KML to GeoJson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92885/ogr2ogr-converting-kml-to-geojson)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I was hoping to have something online, something that it will always be in sync. Even having KML would be good, but having it rendered automatically, without having to manually export it.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do that is to write code that would query your MyMap dynamically for the KML, convert it to GeoJson and load that dynamically on your map (though it would probably be simpler just to use the KML).

Comment: And how can I get the KML through let's say an Ajax call?